# Javascript with datetime-local output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, ionic-framework

Replace my datetime from server:

**Controller**

```
var happensFrom = $scope.eventOccasion.happensFrom;
$scope.ev.eventStart = new Date(happensFrom.replace(' ', 'T'));
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="ev.eventStart" />
<span class="input-label">Começa ({{eventOccasion.happensFrom | amDateFormat:'D/MM/YYYY HH:mm'}})</span>
```

**Output**

```
eventOccasion.happensFrom => 07/14/2015 => 15:30:34 <= (Original Time)

ev.eventStart => 07/14/2015, => 12:30:34 PM <= (Time changed???)
```

Why my time changed?

*This is for edit datetime-local in ionic form.*

Comment: Likely your date was parsed as UTC.  What does the original string value of `happensFrom` look like?

Comment: I need to parse to UTC cause Safari receive Invalid Date if I request directly from server(2015-10-10 00:00:00), my original value of happensFrom is (07/14/2015 15:30:34) my real problem is the time everything else is ok to me.